# how perform web scapring using laravel and the client side

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel

i want to get html contents from url from the client side in javascript or any other alternatives

i had tried the server side in php but the website that im trying to get it is keeps banning my server ip address
and i had tried the ajax way it tells me Cross-Origin Request Blocked: i had tried to allow it but nothing helped .
i want to pass the request on the website im trying to get from the web browser of the client to be safe from getting banned

this is examples from php and ajax request

```
<?php

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.example.com/",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,

            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
                "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en;q=0.6",
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                "origin: https://www.example.com/",
                "referer: http://www.example.com/",
                "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36",
                "x-microsoftajax: Delta=true"
            ),
        ));

         curl_exec($curl);


?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.example.com/',
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    // your code to handle data here
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: If they are blocking you and you do not have authorization to do this it would easily be construed as hacking which has penalties...

Comment: Even the method you are describing won't work no matter how much you try.
CORS, is when you are trying to access a remote website with ajax, which is not allowed unless you have an authorization.
You will also have to make a request to the website with your ip, so anyways you will get blocked.
And finally, to be honest, if i haven't smelled something wrong with this, i would've gave an alternative.. but meeh

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ajax to make a request to your server, and then (in response to that) make a request from your server to a third party server: That request comes from your server.

There is no way to proxy a request and have it still come from the computer the browser is running on.

---

Instead of trying to *evade* the restrictions the third party is imposing on you: Negotiate with them.